# When gets a record struct copied automatically?

Tags: c#, .net-core, struct, record, c#-10.0

Consider the following executable example:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public record struct Record()
{
    public bool DoSomething { get; set; } = false;

    public void SetDoSomething(bool newValue)
    {
        DoSomething = newValue;
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static readonly Record MyObject = new();

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyObject.SetDoSomething(true);

        Console.WriteLine($"MyObject.DoSomething: {MyObject.DoSomething}");
        /* Output:
         * false - current version
         * true  - if MyObject is not readonly or Record is defined as record class
         */
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand, why `DoSomething` is still false, after calling the method which sets the property to true.

My guess is, that a copy gets created when calling the method. It makes sense that this does not happen if `Record` is a reference type (record class). But why gets `MyObject` not copied if I remove the readonly modifier?

Comment: That's the behaviour you would expect from a normal (not record) struct, right? If that is unexpected to you, then this question isn't really about *record* structs, but just how structs work in general.

Answer (score 4):

It is called **Defensive Copy**, which is performed by the C# compilers to enforce the semantic of the value types, it is generally not recommended to mark `readonly` on a non-readonly struct since such things will happen and further causes performance regression, there're also some similar scenarios worth mentioning, more specifically:

> `x.Y` causes a defensive copy of the x if:
>
> - x is a `readonly` field and
> - the type of x is a non-`readonly` struct and
> - Y is not a field.
>
> The same rules are applied when x is an in-parameter, ref readonly local variable or a result of a method invocation that returns a value by readonly reference.

The `record` modifier here really doesn't matter, you mark the field with value type as `readonly` so the compiler thinks that it should preserve the semantic, i.e., the immutability of value types through and through. When you invoke a method or access a property of that field, the compiler won't know if the method or property is actually side-effect free, so it makes a conservative decision, that is, the defensive copy to avoid it.

you can check more information at [The ‘in’-modifier and the readonly structs in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/#readonly-fields-of-the-value-types) and [Avoiding struct and readonly reference performance pitfalls with ErrorProne.NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you see is present not only in record structs, but also non-record structs too. Try removing the keyword `record` and the `()` after the name `Record`, and see the same behaviour.

This is just how calling mutating methods on structs are supposed to work. When you call a mutating method on a struct variable, say `x.F()`, you actually pass a *reference* to `x`, then that reference can be mutated by `F`.

For example, if `Record` is a non-record struct, and `MyObject` is not `readonly`, `MyObject.SetDoSomething(true);` is compiled to the following IL (Try it yourself with [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIBnDKAVzAzoCUZIoATKgG8qdUXVp1gECLjoARCAGUIAWxgYAFtgB2AczqC6u9QG5GpugF8qIsRMIo6i9QuVrNO3QAopMutpgAdwA1AENcFhgASltRYUoxRPklVXUtPToAXn8gsIiYE1irKmtKKhIaISL7UiQuHmg+OgBZAE8AeWAAKx4ObIDAryjCsoS7YmIi+KSxNs6e9gA6ZwxXVI89L2ZI4aLEue7exbX3dN1FgEltBgAHXqGRmdEAegAqOnaWDBuvkD3E94AM3CDBgdDgdDALCgsG0HAAbjAoAxsBBtP8xO9tmDwXRsICWh1Duw8Qx/BAOLBQnw0bhWnRoPVeE1sGS+DBAToYE1QmTYMzxJMxk9Xs8iqVLEA)):

```
    ldsflda valuetype Record Program::MyObject
    ldc.i4.1
    call instance void Record::SetDoSomething(bool)
```

`ldsflda` means "load static field address". I've only found a [small section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#1547-meaning-of-this) of the spec that talks about this when it is talking about boxing of structs (emphasis mine):

> Similarly, boxing never implicitly occurs when accessing a member on a constrained type parameter when the member is implemented within the value type. For example, suppose an interface ICounter contains a method Increment, which can be used to modify a value. **If `ICounter` is used as a constraint, the implementation of the `Increment` method is called with a *reference* to the variable that `Increment` was called on, never a boxed copy.**

Basically, if you don't box structs (you clearly don't here!), their methods are *supposed* to be called by reference. No copies are supposed to be made.

On the other hand, if you call `x.F()` but `x` is `readonly`, you obviously can't translate it to the same code above, since that would mutate the field. What the compiler does, according to SharpLab, is:

```
    ldsfld valuetype Record Program::MyObject
    stloc.0
    ldloca.s 0
    ldc.i4.1
    call instance void Record::SetDoSomething(bool)
```

Basically, it loads the value of the struct to a temporary variable first, and then pass the reference of that variable to `SetDoSomething`.

```
var temp = MyObject;
temp.SetDoSomething();
```

Hence the "copy" behaviour that you see.